# Extract correct parent attribute value by XPath in Kettle / Spoon

Tags: xml, xpath, kettle, spoon

I've the following XML and use kettle spoon **Get XML Data** to extract:

```
<Company cname="ABC">
<Staffs>
    <Manager mname="John">
        <Subordinate sname="Apple">
            <PhoneNo>11111111</PhoneNo>
        </Subordinate>
        <Subordinate sname="Becky">
            <PhoneNo>22222222</PhoneNo>
        </Subordinate>
    </Manager>
    <Manager mname="Peter">
        <Subordinate sname="Cathy">
            <PhoneNo>33333333</PhoneNo>
        </Subordinate>
        <Subordinate sname="Doris">
            <PhoneNo>44444444</PhoneNo>
        </Subordinate>
    </Manager>
</Staffs>
</Company>
```

If I set the **Loop XPath** as **/Company/Staffs/Manager/Subordinate** , I got the incorrect Manager name **(all managers are John!)**.

```
Mname: ../../*[name()='Manager']/@*[name()='mname']
Sname: @*[name()='sname']
PhoneNo: *[name()='PhoneNo']

|#|Mname|Sname|PhoneNo |
|-+-----+-----+--------|
|1|John |Apple|11111111|
|2|John |Becky|22222222|
|3|John |Cathy|33333333|
|4|John |Doris|44444444|
```

Please help, how to get the correct manager name?

```
------------------------
|#|Mname|Sname|PhoneNo |
|-+-----+-----+--------|
|1|John |Apple|11111111|
|2|John |Becky|22222222|
|3|Peter|Cathy|33333333|
|4|Peter|Doris|44444444|
------------------------
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know anythinh about kettle or spoon but IMO if you loop throuh "Subordinate" (so Subordinate is an actual context) you should use these xpaths:

Mname: `parent::Manager/@mname`

Sname: `@sname`

PhoneNo: `PhoneNo`

Comment: Thanks for suggestion.  It works by replacing Mname to **parent::*[name()='Manager']/@*[name()='mname']**

Comment: Indeed, you need only one ../ : ../Manager/@*[name()='mname'] should work.